# Cоздать иерархию процессов с заданным количеством уровней

Tags: linux, c, процесс

Пытаюсь создать иерархию процессов с заданным количеством уровней.
Будет ли такой код создавать иерархию или всего лишь продублирует процессы n-раз ?

```
int main(  )
    {
    int n;   
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Start %d\n", (int)getpid());
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    { 
      if (fork() < 0)
    printf("Fork failure in pid %d\n", (int)getpid());
    }

        printf("i am %d, my parent is %d\n",
                (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());
        while (wait(0) > 0) 
            ;
        printf("Exit %d\n", (int)getpid());

        return(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос не имеет смысла, так как:

1. Функция *fork()* создаёт ДУБЛИКАТ текущего процесса.
2. Созданный процесс является дочерним, по отношению к родительскому, т.е. они ИЕРАРХИЧЕСКИ упорядочены.

Т.е. это не или-или, а И И.
Кроме того, в приведённом Вами исходном тексте функция *fork()* использована неправильно, бессмысленным образом. Что наводит на мысль о том, что Вы не знакомы с основами этого дела...

Рекомендую почитать хотя бы "Управление процессами в операционной системе GNU/Linux. Методические указания к лабораторной работе № 7
по дисциплине «Системное программирование»
для студентов специальности 210302 «Радиотехника»
дневной формы обучения"

Подсказка... Правильный вызов *fork()* должен выглядеть так:

```
pid = fork();
switch ( pid ) {
   case -1:
      prinf("Создание процесса завершилось ошибкой");
      break;
   case 0:
      pid_new = getpid();
      prinf("Я в дочернем процессе, pid=%d\n", pid_new);
      break;
   default:      
      prinf("Я в родительском процессе");
}
```